# Why am I getting a method undefined error in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I'm working on letting users sign in and out of my rails app. The error I get is as follows

> undefined method 'find_by_remember_token'

The method in question is written like this:

```
def current_user
@current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

Any help you can provide in fixing this error would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you can reset your database and migrate in one line:

```
rake db:migrate:reset && rake db:migrate && annotate
```

use the gem annotate in your project to have a better view of your database columns

in your Gemfile add:

```
gem 'annotate'
```

and in console run:

```
bundle update && bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a field in your `users` table called `remember_token` ?

Comment: I created and ran a migration where I added a remember_token to my database, however the remember_token isn't in my schema.rb file. Is there a way to force the database to add the new field? Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem and wanted to include how I fixed it.

First, I made sure I added the required info to the migration:

```
class AddRememberTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :remember_token, :string
    add_index  :users, :remember_token
  end
end
```

then I just dumped my db and remigrated:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

worked for me after that.